# Trying to add polymorphism to template function

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

So yeah, you can't have a template virtual class member function. That makes sense, not trying to figure that part out...and I'm trying like the devil to avoid multiple/virtual inheritance.

I've got a a template class A, and an abstract template class B that inherits from A, and a C that inherits from B.

```
template <typename T>
class A 
{
protected:
   T val; 
public:
   A(T a) {val = a;}
   T val() {return val();}

   template <typename J>
   A<J> cast_as() { return A<J>((J)val); }
};

template <typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
protected:
  int b;
public:
   B(T a) : A(a){b=10*a;}
   virtual foo() = 0;
   //and I'd like, but this can't exist
   //template <typename J>
   //B<J>* BCastAs();

};

template <typename T>
class C : public B<T>
{
protected:
  int c;
public:
  C(T c) : B(c) { c=c+1;}
  virtual foo() override { cout << (a+b+c);}
};

int main() { C<int> c(10); B<double>* b = c.BCastAs<double>();}
```

And I can't think of any way to do that...It feels like it should be possible, as B* does not need to actually know that it is a C (much like the return of a clone call) but i don't know a way to get the c to move over correctly without having virtual template member functions, which is impossible.

Comment: That member function template can exist, no problem.  You just can't make it possible for `C` to override it.

Comment: Maybe some background on the actual problem you're trying to address would be more useful than some abstract classes?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @crowder can't paste actual code, but image buffers "base", building on meta-data and functionality to do some magic in and B, but there may be multiple ways to do the magic in B, so C exists to have its own metadata and functions. Image buffers and their children will need to be able to be cast to other types...

Comment: @aschepler how does B in the template call get a C<J> if it does not know what C is? A curiously recurring template pattern would solve this problem, but is statically polymorphic rather than dynamically polymorphic, which means that anyone who uses this abstract class would need to be a template class, which is ANNOYING.

Comment: Why does `BCastAs` want to return a _pointer_?  If it weren't for that, this would be easy.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams _'which means that anyone who uses this abstract class would need to be a template class'_ Note this isn't true.

Answer (score 1):

The sample code you've posted looks like a having a serious design flaw to me at first glimpse.

Usually it's not necessary to have virtual functions in class templates, because you can use a [CRT pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to avoid them.

You make up the intention that you require inherited classes (this is how you make a template 'abstract'), that implement a defined interface. The interface may or (preferably) not be defined as pure virtual methods (a static interface check would do as well and cause less mysterious compiler error messages in case of missing method implementations).

You can see a sample of such template framework and how to use this technique in my [STTCL template library](http://makulik.github.io/sttcl/).

In short: Use static polymorphism.

**UPDATE:**
And yes, I'm also using pure virtual methods in STTCL, but in a completely different manner (just as basic entry points to couple complete sets of inheritance hierarchies).

Comment: I agree, but the side effects on the code structure is kinda weird. Anything that consumes the base class of the CRT needs to be aware of the template implementation of the final class (and thus be a template itself, with one template argument being C<T>) in order to call the cast function.

Comment: Yes, that's why it's called 'Static Polymorhism'. The final application that instantiates the concrete classes needs (somehow, may be induced) to know all the final types it wants to instantiate. That's what makes it so efficient on small embedded systems, where you know a certain hardware platform to configure your firmware for, and don't need to represent several peripheral  device varieties with run time instantiated interfaces.
And a further aspect: Deriving intermediate classes usually is no problem, the `FinalClass` template parameter is usually pretty transparent.

Comment: And one more point: Specifically for the example I have given with STTCL, FSM's (**Finite** State Machines) have final behavioral implementations and such are somehow naturally able to be designed with this approach (there are other dynamic ways of course).